# JSX element does not have construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsc

Creating a HOC Class that looks around a bunch of Components set in the "child" class.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Container<C = any, P = {}> extends React.Component {

    Components: C[]

    props: React.PropsWithChildren<P>

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                {this.Components.map((Component: C, index) => {

                    return (
                        <Component key={index} />
                    )
                })}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

In the parent class, I'm getting the below error in VSCode.

```
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
```

Comment: Did you try passing the child to the parent component and wrap it inside your HOC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of errors here.  I'm not understanding how this is an HOC or how it works since the property `this.Components` is not set anywhere.  A higher-order component is a function which takes a component and returns a component.  It can be a function which returns a class, but it is not itself a class.

The particular error in your question is due to the generic `C` which is the type of the each component in `this.Components`. You have said that `C` can be literally anything, so it doesn't have to be a valid callable component.  That's why you are getting the error that "JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures."  Get rid of `C` and make your components be the type `React.ComponentType`.  This ensures that they are callable through JSX.

Comment: Apologies for the mis-worded question. Realised when reading your answer that I'd switched to a Class based Component method to resolve what I was doing. Thanks for the answer though. Switching `Components: C[]` to `Components: React.ComponentType[]` worked a treat.